# How can I download previous version of Agora.io iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, agora.io

I try going to [this page](https://docs.agora.io/en/All/downloads?platform=All%20Platforms) but see nothing that can allow me to download previous version of sdk

The version I want to download is iOS 3.1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did think there was a central page for this, but you can take the URL to download the Voice SDK which ends in: `Agora_Native_SDK_for_iOS_v3_3_1_VOICE.zip`

Replace the version with 3.1.2 in the URL:
https://download.agora.io/sdk/release/Agora_Native_SDK_for_iOS_v3_1_2_VOICE.zip

Or for the Video SDK:
https://download.agora.io/sdk/release/Agora_Native_SDK_for_iOS_v3_1_2_FULL.zip

---

Agora does recommend using the latest SDK for the latest updates including security.